# How Does CSS Inheritance work in this scenario?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am setting up two different nav bars, one for mobile and one for desktop version, i currently have the desktop version decently done and working on the mobile version, but when i put both components in a single app.js the mobile navbar.js is reaching out and grabbing properties from my nav < ul < li etc. from the desktop navbar. Is there a way to only include the files that are imported into the js files. In my desktop navbar i have my desktop navbar scss and in my mobile navbar i have my mobile navbar.scss. Here is my app.js setup.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
import 'util/util.js'

import HomePageBody from '../components/homepage/HomePageBody.jsx'
import Footer from '../components/footer/Footer.jsx'
import Menubar from "../components/menubar/MenuBar";
import SideBar from '../components/sidebar/SideBar'


class HomePage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <Menubar />
        <SideBar />
        <HomePageBody />
        <Footer />
      </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

Comment: Should probably tag this reactjs and scss, since the question appears to be straight html css, but is not.

Comment: If you're importing your `.scss` files as `import './menuBar.scss'` inside of `menuBar.js`, the styles defined in `menuBar.scss` will be defined globally. If this is the case, any element in your Sidebar component that matches the style declarations from `menuBar.scss` will have the styles applied to it. A solution would be to use class names to declare styles.